# Angular factory undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, factory

I am working on a very simple factory to be used inside an angular controller. The problem is that the factory doesn't seem to be getting picked up inside the controller. The `console.log` returns `undefined` and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute', 'ngTouch']);

app.controller('AppController', [
'$scope',
'$rootScope',
'myFactory',
function($scope, $routeParams, myFactory) {
    console.log(myFactory)
}]);

app.factory('myFactory', function() {
    return 'test';
});
```

Comment: Is that the exact code? You're missing a comma after `'AppController'`.

Comment: @rayners sorry, not exact code. In the real code there are no syntax errors. The real code has a lot of mush, but these are the only parts relating to the factory/controller communication.

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x8ksfpen/1/

Comment: It may have something to do with being on top of a rails app, but dependecy injection order needed to match the controller input parameter order for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your controller is is injecting $rootScope and then you change it to $routeParams in the function. Have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wkqajL2x/6/ where I have removed those two attributes. It then works fine.

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('AppController', [
'$scope',
'myFactory',
function($scope, myFactory) {
    console.log(myFactory)
}]);

app.factory('myFactory', function() {
    return 'test';
});
```

so you just need to decide which one out of those you really want to use.

Comment: When you annotate your injectables, the names of the variables in the controller doesn't matter any more, so in this case his `$routeParam` variable (although, clearly a mistake) will be `$rootScope`. That is, in fact, the whole point of annotation, such that during code minimization the following would work: `.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "$rootScope", function(a, b){..}])`

Comment: This actually worked for me! I really didn't think it would be dependent on the order but it was definitely the issue as switching the order causes it to be undefined again. Thank you @Leo Farmer